# java.net.UnknownHostException not able to connect to ftp

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons-net

I have ftp port as: `ftp://173.201.0.1/`

I am trying to connect it through following:

```
String Ftp_Path = "ftp://173.201.0.1/";


    public  List<String>  GetFileList()

    {
         String ftpServerIP = Ftp_Path;
         String ftpUserID = Ftp_UserName;
         String ftpPassword = Ftp_Password;

         FTPFile[] downloadFiles = null;

         StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
         FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
         List<String> xlsFiles = null;

         try {
            ftp.connect(Ftp_Path);
            ftp.login(ftpUserID, ftpPassword);

            downloadFiles=ftp.listFiles();

            xlsFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(FTPFile i : downloadFiles) {
                if(i.toString().endsWith(".xls")) {
                    xlsFiles.add(i.toString());
                }
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

         return xlsFiles;

    }
```

But I am getting error on line:

```
ftp.connect(Ftp_Path);
```

Following is the error.

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: ftp://173.201.0.1/
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.net.DefaultSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultSocketFactory.java:92)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:201)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:289)
    at com.amazonaws.mws.samples.ImportRulesPropertyClass.GetFileList(ImportRulesPropertyClass.java:33)
    at com.amazonaws.mws.samples.ManageReportScheduleSample.main(ManageReportScheduleSample.java:74)
```

Plase help me.

I am new with java.

Comment: Try only using the Hostname

Comment: Have you tried without the protocol prefix?
`String Ftp_Path = "173.201.0.1";`

Comment: Use `173.201.0.1` instead of `ftp://173.201.0.1/`
As in example http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html

Comment: are you behind proxy? do you have INTERNET permission added in your manifest?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need to specify the IP.The FTPClient makes a ftp request.It is not similar to http request.Just change

```
String Ftp_Path = "ftp://173.201.0.1/";

to 

String Ftp_Path = "173.201.0.1";
```

Also check whether the ftp port is up and accessible through telnet

Comment: bro, request u to help on this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21986121/java-lang-nullpointerexception-downloading-file-from-ftp-with-listfiles-method