# java.lang.NullPointerException Downloading file from FTP with listFiles method

Tags: java, ftp

I wanted to get all fileNames present on ftp with .xls extension.

Hence i written following code:

```
FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
FTPFile[] downloadFiles = null;
try {
    ftp.connect(Ftp_Path);
    ftp.login(ftpUserID, ftpPassword);

    downloadFiles = ftp.listFiles();

    xlsFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(FTPFile i : downloadFiles) {
       if(i.toString().endsWith(".xls")) {
           xlsFiles.add(i.toString());
       }
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have made sure that files are present on ftp:

[image]

But getting error on line:

```
downloadFiles = ftp.listFiles();
```

I followed syntax from :

http://kodejava.org/how-do-i-get-list-of-files-from-ftp-server/

But getting error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.amazonaws.mws.samples.ImportRulesPropertyClass.GetFileList(ImportRulesPropertyClass.java:39)
    at com.amazonaws.mws.samples.ManageReportScheduleSample.main(ManageReportScheduleSample.java:74)
```

Comment: check first your ftp.connect(Ftp_Path);
            ftp.login(ftpUserID, ftpPassword); ftp connected or not ?

Comment: Where do you initialize ftp?

Comment: @Naren yes its connected, i have kept debugger every where

Comment: @Alexander_Winter above download files as: FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();

Comment: @NaMo it is working same code  .... In which function the code is there ?? ImportRulesPropertyClass.GetFileList is it??

Comment: Read documentation about listFiles() http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#listFiles%28%29. The array should contain null members if the parser fails.

Answer (score 2):

user below code to get files list

```
FTPClient f=FTPClient();
    f.connect(server);
    f.login(username, password);
    FTPListParseEngine engine = f.initiateListParsing(directory);

    while (engine.hasNext()) {
       FTPFile[] files = engine.getNext(25);  // "page size" you want
       //do whatever you want with these files, display them, etc.
       //expensive FTPFile objects not created until needed.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I added:

```
ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
```

in code before:

```
String downloadFiles[]=ftp.listNames("");
```

Its working now

Comment: enterLocalPassiveMode is required if you are runnning your client throught a NAT router or if you have limited visibility to the server. This is a particular case that affects some FTP commands (like LIST, PUT, GET) that opens a second TCP channel that is blocked in some networks.

Comment: @Dubas thanx, i was anware of it...totally new with java